# Differentiating Android BLE Channel

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

When I make a BLE device talk to an Android device, is there a way for the android device to distinguish what advertising channel the BLE device is on? If doing so is impossible in Android, is it possible with Adafruit BLE devices?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not. The information is discarded before the advertisement packet is sent by the receiving Bluetooth controller to its host (Android) over hci. Why do you want this info anyway?

It seems you can do it on Adafruit though, since it uses nRF softdevice, which gives you this info.

Comment: I wanna perform distance estimation using BLE devices, and I am considering all options including Adafruit and android. Could you please give more specific link of Adafruit BLE doc that I should look at? Thank you